# been refused an interview based on conflict of interest

Tags: interviewing

I work in an afterschool club which is based over 2 sites.  My son has applied for a vacancy that came up but he has been refused an interview.  the school is saying it because its conflict of interest - is this legal ?

Comment: Conflict of interest how? Because you work there they won't consider hiring your son? Where are you located?

Comment: And frankly your son is better off getting a job without a parent also being there. It is not good for his career for a parent to be able to rescue him at his job. It is in fact something that makes him very poorly prepared for the real world unless you own the company and are planning to have him inherit it (and even then, most of the people in that position I have known were absolutely incompetent due to being the owner's son and thus not being held accountable for their behavior.)

Comment: i dont know how its conflict of interest.  i work for a big county council and ive not heard or read anything about not been able to employ family members,

Comment: ps my son has worked with me before on a temporary holiday basis and never was a problem

Comment: @lisa It's a potential conflict if you start changing things around to favor the team your son is on (or vice versa) - or if he stops collaborating with your team because he's mad you made him take out the trash in the snow last week.

Comment: You could remove this problem by telling the club you will step down if your son is appointed.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no laws that require an entity to interview a given candidate.

Answer (score 4):

Many businesses have nepotism rules, which means they don't hire any family members of employees.  This can avoid a lot of problems with favoritism.  It is not illegal in the US to have rules like this (even if we answered legal questions).  If they know they can't hire him, there is no reason to interview him either.

From additional information in the comments, you say that he has worked there before on a temporary holiday basis.  It's still possible that there are nepotism rules in place, but only for permanent employees.  But since he has worked there before, it's probably valid to ask what the conflict of interest is.

However, if you do this, don't do it in an accusational manner, nor even seeming to try to change the fact that he is not being interviewed.  Instead, ask because you're curious as to the reason, and are not objecting:

> You said he can't be hired because of a conflict of interest.  He has been hired before, so I was wondering what the conflict of interest is.  I'm not trying to get him an interview - whatever you decide there is fine - but I am interested in the reasons.  Perhaps he will want to apply in the future, and understanding the conflict of interest now will help to know if working in this business will ever been an option.